# Ok Button for Alert Dialog on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

This is my code for an alert, it shows a message when a button is pressed. How can I make an OK Button to dismiss?

```
    Button bm1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(screen4.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Doctor");
            alert.setMessage("message");
            alert.setCancelMessage(null);
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}}
```

I have put `alert.setCancelMessage(null)` but it doesn't show any button to dismiss.

**Solution:**

```
      Button bm1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       bm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(screen4.this);
            alert.setTitle("Doctor");
            alert.setMessage("message");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: For those who suggest `setPositiveButton()` or `setNegativeButton()` on `AlertDialog alert` just Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Change your alertdialog to this:

```
Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(screen4.this);
alert.setTitle("Doctor");
alert.setMessage("message");
alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
alert.show();
```

Comment: I do that, I gives me error and says "The Method setPositiveButton (string null) is undefined for the type AlertDialog"

Comment: @berkkaan, I think it won't work if you pass null as listener. Pass a new Listener there

Comment: @ShreyaShah passing null will just dismiss the alertdialog

Comment: and pls update your answer just like i wrote in my solution so people will see and get the solution.

Comment: Works, but the justifies the button all the way to the right.  How can you center the 'ok' without making a custom layout?

Answer (score 12):

You can create both OK and cancel button for dialog using this,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("Title");
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
```

Comment: builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
 is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

**Couldn't that just be done by only using a positive button?**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Look at this dialog!")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //do things
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton`

```
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface alert, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Do something
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface alert, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Edited:

```
alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do something
        alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
alert.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no any method `setPositiveButton` for `AlertDialog alert`.

Comment: @user370305, Yes, completely missed it was an AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            ab.setTitle("confirm");
            ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            ab.setMessage("Do u want to close this application?");

            ab.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            ab.setNegativeButton("cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "cancle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            ab.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

alert.setPositiveButton or alert.setNegativeButton

Answer (score 0):

```
Button bm1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(screen4.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Doctor");
            alert.setMessage("message");
            alert.setCancelMessage(null);

            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do somthing or dismiss dialog by                dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the AlertDialog.Builder page in the API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

You can set positive, neutral, and negative buttons using the setPositiveButton, setNeutralButton and setNegativeButton methods, respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button bm1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
bm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(screen4.this).create();
    dialog.setTitle("Doctor");
    dialog.setMessage("message");
    dialog.setButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // here you can add functions

           }
    });
    dialog.setButton2("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // here you can add functions
               dialog.dismiss();
    }
    });
    dialog.show();
    }};
```

Comment: It gives error "The Method setButton (Charsquence, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) from the type AlertDialog is deprecated"